# How to get the attribute values from Dynamo DB in Go?

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to retrieve a column from my Dynamo DB table so something like `SELECT users FROM tableName`.

```
db := dynamodb.New(session)
input := &dynamodb.ScanInput{
    TableName:            aws.String("TableName"),
    ProjectionExpression: aws.String("User"),
}

users, err := db.Scan(input)
log.Println("Users:", users, err)
```

The log just prints `Users: {} Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request.`

The response map is null. The table name is the only required field for declaring ScanInput and I am not trying to filter anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: What should the KeyConditionExpression be when I am not trying to query with a specific value?

Comment: Can you update your example code to include `log.Println(users, err)` and the resulting output, for completeness?

Comment: Is `err` nil? If not, it may contain an error object with more information.

Comment: `Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request.`
I am very confused these key condition expressions are for when I want to query a specific item but what should it be when I want it to equal all primary keys?